# How to i get the Value of Store procedure Output value in Entity Frame Work?

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

```
var CaseList = tableValues.Database.SqlQuery<Querys>("exec sp_CaseSearchPYG @UserID",
                    new SqlParameter("@UserID",new Guid("77C48AEE-F27F-47B1-81D4-8C49E2F5BDCB")));
```

//these is my linq query @Query its my OUTPUT parameter of SP

Answer (score 0):

You can get output parameter value by the bellow code.

```
var CaseList = tableValues.Database.SqlQuery<Querys>("exec sp_CaseSearchPYG @UserID, @Query out",
                    new SqlParameter("@UserID", new Guid("77C48AEE-F27F-47B1-81D4-8C49E2F5BDCB")),
                    new SqlParameter("Query", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = DBNull.Value });
```